# No aparece RadioButton PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

Actualmente tengo un sistema de encuestas. El problema es que al momento de ingresar las opciones que tenga la encuesta, coloqué `radio buttons`, pero no me aparecen.

Me aparecen así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo aparece el texto pero no aparece el botón para seleccionar .

Este es mi código:

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['id_pregunta'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id_opcion'] ?>" required> <?php echo $row['valor'] ?></label>
</div>
```

Que esa es la parte en la que está el `radiobutton`.

No sé exactamente porque no me sale la opción.

Comment: Haz clic derecho sobre una de las opciones y selecciona "Inspeccionar", si en el inspector aparece el HTML del radio, entonces el problema es que los estás ocultando por CSS.

Comment: Me tomé el atrevimiento de editar tu pregunta y agregué el código en un snippet... Como puedes observar, si se muestra el radio. El problema debe estar en otra parte de tu código.

Comment: Lo he probado en bootstrap 5 y se ve, aunque no me convence que lo tengas en un `<label>`, pero se ve. ¿Que version de bootstrap usas?

Comment: @masterguru, puedes encerrar cualquier campo de formulario dentro de un `<label>` para facilitar el uso, sin necesidad de incluir el atributo `for="id_de_campo"` y no afecta el funcionamiento ni la vista, al menos cuando no hay reglas CSS específicas.

Comment: visto, gracias @Triby, yo empecé a usar `<label>` cuando aprendí bootstrap años atrás, y no sabia esto otro que acabo de verificar en MDN, perfecto (en la doc de bootstrap no ví jamás un ejemplo de eso así, por eso no lo tenia claro)

Comment: @masterguru estoy utilizando Bootstrap 4.1.2 para esos estilos, pero no me aparece